# Is this the correct way to stop a function and restart it with new data?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a function which does a bunch of searching and setting fields. Now, I want it to stop doing that and restart as soon as I change anything, is this the correct way of doing that?

The plan is that I don't have work being done that is no longer used, and that slower updates don't finish after a more recent, faster update

```
private var autoUpdateJob: Job = Job()

(...)

// Something happens (eg. an onTextChangedListener in an EditText gets triggered)
launch {
    autoUpdateJob.cancelAndJoin()
    autoUpdateJob = launch { flight = autoValues() }
}
```

Comment: A bit better is to put `autoUpdateJob.cancel()` before `launch` and then `join()` on it within the `launch`.

Comment: just to be sure: Still have an outer and an inner `launch` but get the `cancel()` outside of both?

Comment: Moving `cancel` out of `launch` makes it execute immediately, that's the slight difference. You could get rid of the inner `launch` as well, reusing the outer one, but then you'd have to mess with the job variable a bit more.